# Java regex "\A" boundary match

Tags: java, regex, matching

I am looking for some help with this regex. I have strings of varying length, and want to match only the beginning. The strings have newlines in them so it seems \A is the way to go.

I want regex that will match all the following cases:

```
OPTIONAL: [any whitespace/newlines/etc] 
OPTIONAL: <?.*?>
OPTIONAL: [any whitespace/newlines/etc]
MANDAORY: <lemon>
OPTIONAL: anything afterwards.
```

Since the strings can get huge, the final Optional matching is making this be extremely slow.

My initial solution was:

```
"(^\\s*<?.*?>\\s*<lemon>)[\\s\\S]*|(^\\s*<lemon>.*)[\\s\\S]*"
```

This is extremely convoluted and matches the entire string instead of just the start

My current best try is:

```
"\\A(?:\\s*<?.*?>)?\\s*<lemon>"
```

However, this does not work if there is anything after `mon>`, then the match fails.

Has anyone got any ideas as to why? Examples on `\A` are sparse and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is the notion of grouping. I've taken your regex and put it into `(` brackets

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\A(?:\\s*<?.*?>)?\\s*<lemon>).*");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("   <?.*?>    <lemon> hi   ");
 if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
 }
```

group 0 will the whole expression

group 1 will what you need.

This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) might explain how groups work

> I am simply looking for a way to get a binary answer similar to String.matches(), which upon finding a match stop going through the string

Take this: `\\A(?:\\s*<?.*?>)?\\s*<lemon>(.*?)` with no grouping

Comment: I am not trying to group it (or get what matches), I am simply looking for a way to get a binary answer similar to String.matches(), which upon finding a match stop going through the string. if I append a .* (and [\\s\\S]*) then it goes through the whole string and passes. I want to avoid this and just get a pass the second the regex is matched at the start of the input.

Comment: Thanks for the response; unfortunately your edited answer does not work, and it goes through ALL of the string ([\\s\\S]* is req for it to work, but still extremely slow which was my initial issue)

Comment: Ok, I've added `?` to make it non-greedy. Try now. `\\A(?:\\s*<?.*?>)?\\s*<lemon>(.*?)`

Comment: it matches now but it is still rather slow....I don't think I fully understand the \A. I just ran some tests and \\A<?.*?> does NOT match <?aksljd?>a (where a == . )

Comment: Why not change `\\A` to `^`?